# Connecting via JDBC to MS SQL Server raise an SQLServerException

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

I know this question has been asked many times before.  However I cannot seem to get right.

I'm trying to connect to a local MS SQL server instance with Java (I have no problem to connect to this server with .NET).

I'm using `sqljdbc.jar` library with the following code:

```
String url = "jdbc:microsoft:sqlserver://";
String serverName= "MPRSNT2765/SQLEXPRESS";
String portNumber = "1433";
String databaseName= "MogGPS";
String un = "admin";
String pw = "admin";        
String selectMethod = "cursor"; 

String connectionUrl = url+serverName+":"+portNumber+";databaseName="+databaseName+";selectMethod="+selectMethod+";";

Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
con = java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl,un,pw);
```

I get the following stacktrace:

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The TCP/IP connection
>   to the host MPRSNT2765/SQLEXPRESS, port 1433 has failed. Error:
>   "null. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of
>   SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at
>   the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked
>   by a firewall.".  at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(SQLServerException.java:190)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.ConvertConnectExceptionToSQLServerException(SQLServerException.java:241)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SocketFinder.findSocket(IOBuffer.java:2243)
>     at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel.open(IOBuffer.java:491)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:1309)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:991)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:827)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:1012)
>     at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)  at
>   bcapi.SQL.Init(SQL.java:29)   at bcapi.App3.main(App3.java:33)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Compare your URL with the one from the manual: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378428%28v=sql.110%29.aspx

Comment: how did you get sqlite mixed in?

Comment: Oh my goodness, I had a SQLLite library in the mix as well.  Well I removed it now and it is still not working, however a different error.  I have updated the error in my post

Answer (score 2):

remove "microsoft" from the URL:

```
String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://";
```

Comment: I have done that, and it asked that I use sqljdbc4 instead of sqljdbc.  After done that I still get the same error:

java.sql.SQLException: invalid database address:

Comment: Looks like `String serverName= "MPRSNT2765/SQLEXPRESS";` is also incorrect

Answer (score 1):

Normal URL to access SQL Server in java is :

```
jdbc:sqlserver://MPRSNT2765:1433;databaseName=MogGPS
```

URL:

```
jdbc:sqlserver://<server_name>:<server_port>;databaseName=<db_name>
```

Do not use `MPRSNT2765/SQLEXPRESS` use only server name `MPRSNT2765`

So that modified url and servername as below:

```
String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://";
String serverName = "MPRSNT2765";
```